# удаление объекта в C++

Tags: c++

Есть связной список , во время когда удаляется из списка один узел,
по идее его надо удалить , поскольку он был создан через new.
Я использую оператор delete ,но после этого оператора выводится все так же
адрес указателя. Почему???

```
 class LinkedList{

private:
    class Node{
    public:
        int a;
        Node* next;
        ~Node(){
            delete next;
        }
    };
    Node* head;
    int lenght;
public:
    LinkedList(){
        lenght=0;
        head=nullptr;
    }


    void add(int x) {

        Node* current = new Node;
        current->a = x;
        current->next = nullptr;
        if(head==NULL){
            head=current;
        }else{
            Node *node=head;
            while(node->next!=NULL){
                node=node->next;
            }
            node->next=current;

        }
            lenght++;
    }


    void remove(int index){
        Node *temp=head;
        int count=0;
        while(count<index-1){
            temp=temp->next;
            count++;
            }

        Node *rem=temp->next;
        Node *next=rem->next;
        temp->next=next;
        lenght--;
        delete rem;
        cout<<rem<<endl;
    }

    bool isEmpty(){
        return lenght==0;
    }

    int get(const  int index){
        Node *temp=head;
        int i=0;
        while(i<index){
            temp=temp->next;
            i++;
        }
        return temp->a;
    }

    int *toArray(){
        int arr[lenght];
        Node *temp=head;
        for(int i=0;i<lenght;i++){
            arr[i]=temp->a;
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        return arr;
    }
  int size(){
        return lenght;
    }
};

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"rus");

 LinkedList obj;

        obj.add(1);
        obj.add(2);
        obj.add(3);
        obj.add(4);
        obj.add(5);

        obj.remove(2);
for(int i=0;i<obj.size();i++)
     cout<<obj.get(i)<<endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: может быть адрес места в памяти, а не адрес указателя? Почему указателю перестать туда указывать?

Comment: `void remove(int index){
        Node *temp=head;
        int count=0;
        while(count<index-1){
            temp=temp->next;
            count++;
            }

        Node *rem=temp->next;
        Node *next=rem->next;
        temp->next=next;
        lenght--;
        delete rem;
        cout<<rem<<endl;
    }`  в конце я удаляю узел, который вытащил из списка, но консоль выводит адрес памяти.

Comment: и правильно делает.

Comment: rem=nullptr; напиши

Comment: Это разве удалит объект?Это в java объект удаляется после потери связи с ссылочной переменной, в c++ насколько я понял он останется в памяти

Comment: это сделает указатель не валидный и предотвратит обращение к чужой памяти

Comment: Это здорово, но как удалить его вообще из памяти?

Comment: delete освобождает память на которую указывает указатель

Comment: Получается объект тогда должен быть удален, поскольку указатель хранил адрес памяти на удаляемый из списка узел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

оператор `delete rem;`  освобождает память, выделенной для обьекта, на который указывает `rem`.   Но в `rem`,  как и раньше, записан этот адрес, только с той разницей, что этот адрес  может использоваться  для других обьектов. Так как этот указатель создан в функции, он уничтожается сам после выхода из функции, и его значение вы не возвращаете из функции, поэтому несанкцианированный доступ к освобожденной части памяти(уничтоженного обьекта) вы не сможете иметь. Если есть ситуация, что вы где то должны хранить этот указатель, то его перед хранением нужно обнулять, т.е. присвоить ноль(nullptr)